# How to display total (sum of column) in magento grid during CSV export

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid

I have made a custom admin grid in which I have fetched two different columns through rendering, However now I want to display the total text (sum of all values) at the bottom while exporting it to CSV, like it is done in the report grids. How can I use and export the total row in a custom grid?

Comment: Total from which table? Please add more info.

Comment: I am applying the join of 'sales/order' on one custom table of my extension to find the revenue generated from the store.

Comment: If you can share your _prepareCollection() code for grid, it may be more helpful to us to find way, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In grid I believe you cannot add two columns, you must query it from db table. So if you really want to add two columns then please have some code to add them and fetch them to new column so that you can query to display in grid.

If you want to display grand total from `sales/order` table then-

you need to join your custom table with `sales/order`. You will need to use `join`-

```
<?php
   $your_collection = Mage::getModel('module/model')->getCollection();
   $your_collection
        ->getSelect()->joinLeft(array(
             'order'=> sales_flat_order), 
             'order.order_id = main_table.order_id', 
             array('order.base_grand_total')
        );
?>
```

Then add your new column with `base_grand_total`.

**Important**

You must have `order_id` as foreign key in your custom table. You can see I have used `main_table.order_id` here.
`main_table` means your `custom_table` and `order_id` means `order_id` in your custom table which is `FK` linked to `sales_flat_order` table.

Have't tested but should work. Good luck.